# read form file in webapp2 -google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, webapp2

I'm uploading an xml file using multipart/form/data and need to read the xml file content  and print the xml file content in the response.write()

```
MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/f1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div><input type="file" name="filecoll"></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Submit "></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
         self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)
class formfiless(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('filecoll')))

        f=self.request.get('filecoll')
        data=f.read()


        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/',MainPage),
    ('/f1',formfiless),
], debug=True)
```

when I tried to read the form file the following error occured.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\uniphoreC08\Desktop\upload_grammar\helloworld.py", line 35, in post
    f.read()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Can you make the question clearer, what exactly are you trying to do. Maybe elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Why did you tag this question gas?

Comment: Also, it's probably webapp2 not webapp1.  Sloppy.  Kids nowadays...

Comment: Er, in the title? Oh, you corrected it after commenting.

Comment: okay try to help  on this program

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
self.request.get('filecoll')
```

appears to be yielding a unicode string, not a file object. In the next line, you are calling the read() method as if it were a file object. Hence

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code which will write xml file as string in the web.

```
  class MPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
     uploaded_file  = self.request.body
     self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
     self.response.write(str(uploaded_file))
```

instead of the request arguements, use the request body and  and body_file: body is the body content as a byte string and body_file provides a file-like interface to the same data: